# Codeception testing form with select autocomplete ajax field

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, codeception

#### Behavior in production environment.

I have a form with an autocomplete select box, where its initial representation is empty:

```
<select name="customer"></select>
```

Latter, when I click, an ajax request load and populate the first page of options (I don't need type anything at this time).

Then, I can choose one option and to submit the form using ajax. The entity is saved successfully and I show a flash message "Item has been successfully created."

#### Testing behavior in Codeception environment:

**I need test the behavior previously explained** using functional test (Codeception)

```
$I->amOnPage('/create');
$I->selectOption('select[name="customer"]', 1); //choose option with value = 1
$I->submitForm('form');
$I->canSee('Item has been successfully created.');
```

Result:

> [InvalidArgumentException] Input "customer" cannot take "1" as a value (possible values: ).

This not works! of course, the select element is empty (no options).

**So my question is obvious at this moment, how can I test this scenario?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to question later:

http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#submitForm.

For those case where the fields (`<select>`) are populated dynamically (AJAX), simply omits the `$I->selectOption(...)` statement and pass the values to `$I->submitForm('form', [...]);` directly, so:

```
$I->amOnPage('/create');
$I->submitForm('form', ['customer' => 1]);
$I->canSee('Item has been successfully created.');
```

It's enough, my tests they are green again :)

Answer (score 0):

```
I.fillField("#inputName", "first three letters for ex..");
const required = '#theIdOfRequiredSelectedElement'
I.click(required)
```

---

or the required may be the XPath of the item
**To  get the XPath of the item you want to select the item by
catch the item on the elements side of (inspect of the browser) then right click, choose copy then choose XPath**